# Creating Python virtual environment in different version than installed on Windows

Tags: python

To run some script I need specific version of python **(3.7.1)**.
On my PC I have python 3.7.3

For creating virtual environment I am using:

```
    python -m venv virtual
```

Which gives me fully functional python but in version 3.7.3 and I need 3.7.1

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Better use [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) in which it is very easy to maintain virtual environments

Comment: Anaconda is **not** specifically easier to configure virtual environments with. There are IDEs that manage it for you regardless of which distribution you use, such as pycharm.

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal going back trough my old questions. Yes, anaconda is the answer to a lot of things :D

Answer (score 0):

virtualenv can only create environments for versions of python installed on the machine.

You may install multiple versions in parallel on windows then select which one to use.

Answer (score 0):

Just install Python 3.7.1. Assuming you are using [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), create your environment as:

```
virtualenv -p /home/username/opt/python-3.7.1/bin/python Project_Name
```